# Computationnal geometry: vector, basis, point and coordinate system?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, computer-science, computational-geometry

I am trying to build a small geometrical library in C++, that is mathematically consistent (not so false). The goal here is to construct two concepts: vectors and points. I am not sure that the following formulation is consistent (and if not, how to modify it).

First, the vectors. To construct a vector, one need two elements:

- a vector space `vector_space<class Field, unsigned int Dimension>` is defined by:

  - a field (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$)
  - a dimension (e.g. $3$)
- a basis of N vectors if the vector space has N dimensions

Having that, when one calls `my_vector[0]`, or `my_vector[1]`, the returned number corresponds to the components of the vector according to the given basis.

Now points (and here I am not sure of what I am saying) (you can add vectors, add a vector to a point, but not add two points). As for vector, one need two elements:

- an affine space `affine_space<class VectorSpace>` that can be defined from:

  - a vector space
- a coordinate system

Having that, when one call `my_point[0]`, or `my_point[1]`, the returned number corresponds to the coordinate of the point in the provided coordinate system.

Here are my questions:

1. Does it make sense (mathematically speaking) ?
2. Is there a better approach (mathematically speaking) ?
3. Is it correct to say that a coordinate system is for a point, what a basis is for a vector?

Comment: Are you trying to do something with projective geometry?  I find distinguishing between points and vectors is only really common when doing projective or conformal geometry--e.g. when working in homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: If you're using the point to talk about position, then there is no useful difference from a vector (a point then is represented by the vector from the origin to the location).  If you're worried about topology, you might want to separate the classification.  Explicitly prohibiting "point + point" while allowing "point - point" (resulting in a vector) is probably more trouble than it's worth.

What is the problem domain you have in mind?

Comment: I think your math is fine - it makes sense to me at least.  From the programming point of view, I do this (in a simpler context) and think it's worthwhile as I don't want "point + point" to compile if I type it by accident.  Just like I don't want `char* + char*` to compile, even though `char* + std::ptrdiff_t` is fine.  It is Haskell rather than C++, but are you aware of [Conal Elliot's vector-space package](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Vector-space) ?  I think that it is a good theoretical match for what you are doing.